# Syntax-Highlighting won't recognize all CSS keywords

Tags: bug, status-deferred, design, syntax-highlighting

I just discovered a strange behavior of the CSS syntax highlighting feature which you can see in the following code example:

```css
.first_rule {
   color: red;
}
.second_rule:hover {
   color: blue;
}
```

`.first_rule` will have a plain black color, but `.second_rule` will be highlighted in blue because it is interpreted a keyword. It seems as if `.first_rule` would also become a keyword, as soon as I append a pseudo class (or anything else beginning with a  colon) to it. This lets the user assume that there is a difference between the two kinds of identifiers, but indeed there isn't.

Is this worth the effort to fix it, in order to keep StackOverflow the most user friendy page on the web? :-)

PS: Sorry, StackOverflow **Meta** uses a very low contrast for syntax highlighting. Please use Firebug, if you can't see this properly or temporarily paste it to the real StackOverflow.

Comment: That's because `second_rule` is a moderator.

Comment: SE does not make the script that highlights, it uses [Google Code Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/). Go submit a bug report if you want.

Comment: Oh, I did not know that this script was used. I quickly posted it over there too: http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=216 Thanks.

Comment: I have noticed this for a very long time, however I never bothered to file an issue over there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, SO depends on [Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) to do the heavy lifting here. Get a fix into that, and we'll deploy it.

Comment: I tried my best and I hope they'll look after this: http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=216 Thank you.